# Ionic framework and angularjs form creation

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created a signup form with the help of ionic framework and Angular-JS . After filling the form details, from one input field to another, when i hit enter button I need the cursor to move to next field. I tried it but didn't get it. Help me for that output?

Comment: could any one tell me the meaning of below line      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

Answer (score 0):

you need to make custom directive, this code may help you

```
.directive('focus', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope,elem,attrs) {

      elem.bind('keydown', function(e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code === 13) {
          e.preventDefault();
          elem.next().focus();
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: do i need to make any changes in index.html file if this directive is added

Comment: what is 'focus' in the directive?

Comment: could u help me once again?

Comment: you need to use 'focus' as attribute in your html page, and you need to import directive js file in to <script> tag

Comment: just reffer this link  http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/custom-directives.html

Comment: what about preventDefault() function?

Comment: preventDefault() means stops the default action of an element

Comment: if you dont mind plz tell cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);  and cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true); what happens in each case??

Answer (score 0):

Can you please put your html code for the form.

and for inputs you can add "required".

for example :

```
<ion-content>
<form class="list" name="login" ng-submit="login.$valid && login(user)">

        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
        <span class="input-label">USERNAME</span>
        <input type="text" name="userName" ng-model="user.userName" placeholder="name" required>
      </label>
          <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
        <span class="input-label">PASSWORD:</span>
        <input type="text" name="userPass" ng-model="user.userPass"  placeholder="password" required>
      </label>  

          <button class="button  button-assertive" type="submit">LOGIN</button> 

    </form>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: it is in ionic but not in html

Comment: in <ion-content> we have this above code </ion-content>

Comment: the above is similar to my ionic code but not getting the required output

Comment: Can you edit your question above and add your html code please ?

Comment: <form class="list">
 <ion-list>
<label class="item item-input">
<input type="text" ng-model="data.firstName" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="15">
</label>
<label class="item item-input">
<input type="text" ng-model="data.lastName" placeholder="Last Name" maxlength="15">
</label>
<button type="submit">submit</button>

Comment: your code has nothing to do with min,  you need to use required in the inputs, plus you need to read more about using angular with forms if you want to validate the inputs

Comment: i cant understand what ur saying?

Comment: there is no need to validate...  i needed only thing is i should go to 1st text-field to 2nd on pressing enter ket that's it..

Comment: yhaa, using required in the <input/> would solve that problem.

Comment: i have used it right <input type="text" and etc>then..what ur asking?

Comment: try this <input type="text" required> ,then check if this solve your problem :)

Comment: how that plunker is useful to me ?

Comment: i have deleted the plnker , you only need to do this :<input type="text" required>

Comment: no nothing is working to it ..what is the meaning in puting required in input tag

Comment: it is mean that you have to insert something in the input before submitting , so when you click enter it should take you to the another input , because Enter = submitting .

Comment: ya i understand i know i need to enter something but what to enter that I dont know that's why i posted here..

Comment: sorry , but your not clear with what you exactly you wan't . depending on your question , my answer above should work .